# Binding best practise

Tags: angular

I have a component that accept a string as Input paramenter.
The string should be localized so I bind that string is this way:

```
<drawer-item [text]="getSectionName (Routes.Companies)" >...
```

In this way everything works perfectly but I put a break-point into the *getSectionName* function and I noticed that this function is called **a lot** of times.
On the startup is called 5-6 times, and then every time I do something in the app it is called again.

Is this a correct behavior or it is dangerous for the performances?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**
the pipe:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'route',
    pure: false
})
export class RoutePipe implements PipeTransform {
    static i:number = 0;
    transform(route: Route) {
        switch (route.state) {
            case Routes.StartPage.state:
            console.log (RoutePipe.i++);
                return "H";
            case Routes.Companies.state:
                return "G";
            case Routes.Settings.state:
                return "F";
            case Routes.Users.state:
                return "E";
            case Routes.CoursesSources.state:
                return "D";
            case Routes.DocumentSources.state:
                return "C";
            case Routes.Notifications.state:
                return "B";
            case Routes.NonDocumentalExpirations.state:
                return "A";
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
A very good explanation about pipes can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using functions in binding expressions is discouraged because of the performance implications you mentioned.

Prefer assingning function results to fields and bind to this fields instead.

In your concrete example a pipe would probably be the appropriate solution.

Comment: But even if there is `expression` OR `variable reference`, that expression is going to evaluate when CD runs. so how performance will matter? apology, If I missed something..

Comment: Comparing identity of two values is cheap, calling functions is expensive in comparison (nothing compared to for example an HTTP request though) but it can sum up if you have lots of bindings.

Comment: Using a pipe it is still called a lot of times. At this point I think that this is the normal behavior of Angular2

Comment: How do you use the pipe? In `devMode` it's aleays called twice where it's only called ones in `prodMode`.

Comment: OP updated with the pipe. You are right, in devMode is called 18 times, in prodMode is called 6 times

Comment: If you use `pure: false` it's the same as binding to a function. Without the pipe is only called when the input value changed.